# Сircular Progress Bar (смена цвета)

Tags: android, progress-bar

Хотел поинтересоваться как можно менять цвет прогрессбара во время выполнения (после завершения одного вращения), наподобие того, что реализовано в приложениях от google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой индикатор чаще всего используется для обновления содержимого списков. Он является часть SwipeRefreshLayout, и цвета добавляются таким способом:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW, Color.MAGENTA)
```

Сам swipRefreshLayout добавляется в макет таким образом:

```
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="66dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">


        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list_res"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

То есть внутри него может быть список например, или другое содержимое которое вы хотите обновлять. Так же если хотите отдельный элемент, то я бы посоветовал [библиотеку](https://github.com/lsjwzh/MaterialLoadingProgressBar) в которой тоже реализованы данные функции.

Comment: А к обычному ProgressBar данный метод, я так понимаю, не применим, и без сторонней библиотеки не обойтись?

Comment: если речь идет о приложениях гугл, то там вероятнее всего используют такой прием, если же вы хотите использовать такой progress bar отдельно, нужно брать библиотеку